# after calling a method the rest of code are not working in java

Tags: java, methods

I tried to call a method(1) in another method(2). But after calling 1 method in 2 method the rest of the code lines not working in 2 method. Solution please.

first method

```
public static void student(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] student_id=new String[150];        
    System.out.print("Enter Student ID   : ");
    for(int i =0;i<student_id.length;i++){      
    student_id[i] = input.nextLine();

    String[] student_name=new String[150];      
    System.out.print("Enter Student Name : ");
    for(int j =0;j<student_name.length;j++){
    student_name[j] = input.nextLine();
    
    }
}}
```

second method

```
 public static void addNewStudent(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("|                                ADD NEW STUDENT                                     |");
    System.out.print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    System.out.println();
    
    student(); //calling 1 method.rest of codes are not working.

    System.out.println();   
    System.out.print("Student has been added successsfully. Do you want to add a new student (y/n): ");
    String yn = input.nextLine();
    
    if (yn.equals("y")){ 
        clearConsole();
        addNewStudent();
        } else {
            clearConsole();
            homePage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well you've got 2 for loops going 150 times each, so you'll have to enter names and id's 300 times before that method returns, but provided you do sit there and enter 300 strings, I don't see anything that would prevent the code from continuing.

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop runs `150` times and reads a line, the inner loop runs `150 * 150` times and reads a line. That totals to `150 + 150 * 150 = 22650` lines to be read.

So the question is why a student would have 150 IDs and 22500 names.

There is definitely a flaw in the logic, also since addNewStudent() goes recursively on new students and does not even return when no more students are needed.